# Bash - How to call a function declared in a parent shell?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I am writing a bash script that calls functions declared in the parent shell, but it doesn't work.

For example:

```
$ function myfunc() { echo "Here in myfunc" ; }
$ myfunc
Here in myfunc
$ cat test.sh 
#! /bin/bash

echo "Here in the script"
myfunc
$ ./test.sh 
Here in the script
./test.sh: line 4: myfunc: command not found
$ myfunc
Here in myfunc
```

As you can see the script `./test.sh` is unable to call the function `myfunc`, is there some way to make that function visible to the script?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
$ export -f myfunc
```

in the parent shell, to [export](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exit-114) the function.

Comment: @Andrew: Right!  There are some answers that just can't be improved upon.

Comment: These things should be better documented

Answer (score 3):

@OP, normally you would put your function that every script uses in a file, then you source it in your script. example, save

`function myfunc() { echo "Here in myfunc" ; }`

in a file called /path/library. Then in your script, source  it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/library
myfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works but I noticed `${0}` takes parent's value:
Maybe more useful if you don't want to have a bunch of export calls in your scripts.

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash

func()
{
  echo func "${1}"
}

func "1"
$(. ./script2)
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/bash

func "2"
```

Output:

```
[mymachine]# ./script1
func 1
func 2
```