# Calling bash functions from sub process

Tags: bash, subprocess

I'm not sure if its possible,  but I'm looking for a way to call a bash function from its subprocess.  It could be something like:

```
function testfunc() { echo test function; }
bash -c 'testfunc'
```

This doesn't work obviously,  but is there any way to achieve something like this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199455/bash-how-to-call-a-function-declared-in-a-parent-shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ function blargh () {
> echo $1
> }
$ export -f blargh
$ bash
$ blargh hi there
hi
$ exit
$ bash -c "blargh hi there"
hi
```

`export -f` is the non-obvious bit.

```
$ help export
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.

    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.

    Options:
      -f    refer to shell functions
    ...
```