# Sourcing function file in bash_profile and bashrc but still doesn't work

Tags: function, bash

It works in the interactive shell but not from in a script.  This script and the trace that follows demostrates:

```
set -x
tail -n 2 ../.bash_profile
tail -n 2 ../.bashrc
cat ../FUNC_FILE
FUNC
cat testfunc
testfunc

***14:43:56 502 ~/work>FUNC
imafunc
***14:44:02 503 ~/work>t
++ tail -n 2 ../.bash_profile
. ~/FUNC_FILE
compgen -A function  # List all functions
++ tail -n 2 ../.bashrc
. ~/FUNC_FILE
compgen -A function  # List all functions
++ cat ../FUNC_FILE
function FUNC () { echo imafunc; }
++ FUNC
./t: line 5: FUNC: command not found
++ cat testfunc
FUNC
++ testfunc
./testfunc: line 1: FUNC: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199455/bash-how-to-call-a-function-declared-in-a-parent-shell).  You need to export the function after sourcing it in ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me.  Your demonstration doesn't really demonstrate the problem, though.  Nowhere in there did you source the scripts you cat'ed.

My working example:

```
bash$ cat testfunction
function thingie () { echo "Ima function"; }
bash$ cat dofunction
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/this/directory/testfunction
thingie
bash$ ./dofunction
Ima function
```

Vs. the non-working example:

```
bash$ cat dontdofunction
#!/bin/bash
cat /homes/bgerard/personal/tmp/testfunction
thingie
bash$ ./dontdofunction
function thingie () { echo "Ima function"; }
./dontdofunction: line 3: thingie: command not found
```

Use "." or (equivalently) "source" in place of "cat" and it should work.

Comment: The functions are sourced in ~/.bash_profile and in ~/.bashrc.  Why isn't that enough?

Comment: Because your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` don't seem to be sourced from inside of your `t` script.  I see you `tail`ing them, but not sourcing them.  In other words, `t` doesn't actually act on anything inside of `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`; it merely echoes part of their contents using `tail`.

Comment: When I open a new Terminal window my .bash_profile runs and I am able to call FUNC.  If I run a script like t shouldn't it inherit FUNC?  I'm tail'ing those files just to prove I'm sourcing ~/FUNC_FILE in them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to source the functions in the script and want the script to see them like you can in an interactive shell, you need to export the function as answered in [Exporting a function in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell)