# How do I call a bash function in sub-script?

Tags: bash, function

Consider the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun() {
  echo "hello $1"
}

echo "fun world" | parallel
```

Now, the function `fun` is not available in the script echoed by `echo`.

Is there a way to make it available / export it?

Edit: See [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: Nothing you aren't going to have to jump through at least half a dozen hoops to make work.

Comment: @PesaThe The string `"fun world"` is a small script.

Comment: Can you explain more on your requirement. It is quite vague (atleast to me)

Comment: A true "subshell" is a shell that's `fork()`ed from the main shell with no intervening `exec`-family syscall. Those have *all* functions available.

Comment: ...if you mean "a shell started by the `parallel` command" (which doesn't fit into the traditional definition of "subshell"), then we're in the space of `export -f`, and this question is duplicative of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199455/bash-how-to-call-a-function-declared-in-a-parent-shell

Comment: Also pertinent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814360/gnu-parallel-and-bash-functions-how-to-run-the-simple-example-from-the-manual

Comment: @bitmask, if you believe the flagged duplicates don't answer your question, please [edit] to describe how you attempted to apply their advice, and the exact errors encountered during those attempts.

Comment: @bitmask, btw, for future reference: `parallel` is not part of bash, not *written in* bash, and otherwise not covered in the bash tag -- there's a whole separate tag for questions about GNU Parallel, and in the future, asking questions about it with that tag is likely to get a better reception.

Comment: Replace `parallel` with `env_parallel` and it works. You will, however, need to activate `env_parallel` once, by using `env_parallel --install`, and starting a new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function name inside quotes, the correct syntax is:

```
echo $(fun world) | parallel
```

The output from the `echo` ("hello world") will be passed to `parallel` through the pipe, so it will be up it it to do something with it.

EDIT:

I might have misunderstood.  If you want a script called `parallel` to execute the function then there are a few issues.  If `bash` then you need to export it as @CharlesDuffy said:

```
export -f fun
```

but beware that not all shells support exported functions, so be sure that `parallel` is a `bash` script.

Comment: or `fun world | parallel`.

Comment: @Cyrus:  yup, not sure why the OP want's an `echo`, I took that to be a simplification.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP wants `parallel` to start a shell that in turn runs the function. That's not an unreasonable request -- GNU parallel actually has explicit support for this kind of thing (though I'd rather it didn't -- part of why I prefer `xargs -P` is GNU Parallel's approach of throwing in every conceivable feature).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ah, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: No, I want `fun` to be run by `parallel`. This runs `hello world` in `parallel`.

Comment: @bitmask, note that when a program calls another program, the OS-level interface used to do that is the `execv` syscall. That syscall takes the name of an executable to start -- at that low-level interface, there is absolutely no way to invoke a shell function from any program that isn't a shell interpreter, *unless you pass the executable name of a shell able to interpret that function*. That's the general rule, though -- `parallel` is full of contextually-dependent magic, so rules often don't apply to it.

Comment: Just found the Linux `man` page for it.  It has an example:  `parallel sh -c "echo hi; sleep 2; echo bye" -- 1 2 3`  and that should work if the `sh` is replaced by `bash` and the function is exported.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  actually, if the function is exported then it can be picked-up  from the environment.  Many moons ago I wrote a Perl script to translate (to Perl) and execute a bash function that had been exported.  It was as horrible as it sounds.  No, wait, it was worse.

Comment: @cdarke, sure, but what I said above is that you still need to have a program that "is a shell interpreter". In the example you give, you wrote one (or at least a momentarily adequate subset) in Perl.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  sorry I mis-read your comment.

Comment: It appears to work with `export -f`.

Comment: If you prefer not to use `export -f` then replacing `parallel` with `env_parallel` will work, too. You just need to activate it: `env_parallel --install; bash`.